# (Dynamically) Decrease the actual image size for downloads

Tags: images, feedburner

I am using feedburner (give it the url of my RSS feed). Each of my feed item have an image, is there a way to lower the actual image size so that people dont have to download the real size?

**EDIT FROM COMMENTS**

The url of the image is one of the item description. I resized it :

```
<img width="200" height="200" border="2" {{data['child']['']['image'][0]['child']['']['description'][0]['data']}} />
```

so that it has a smaller size.
But then I realized that for mobile user we don't want them to download the original image which can be too big. That made me wonder what would be a way to reduce the size of the image before it is downloaded?

Comment: Answer to "is there a way" is "yes" almost universally. Details matter. How are you adding images to items, are they just in post content? What had you looked into and tried for achieving it?

Comment: the url of the image come with the item.I resized it with css (`<img width="200" height="200" border="2" {{data['child']['']['image'][0]['child']['']['description'][0]['data']}} />`)so that it has a thumbnail. But then i realized that for mobile user we don't want them to download the original image which can be too big an was wondering what would be a way to reduce the size of the image before it is downloaded.

Comment: You should add important info like this directly to your question via an [edit]. Some people doesn't read comments, so this vital information is lost to them.

Answer (score -1):

You probably  must do a function on function.php file in to your template.

Reference1 : [How to edit the wordpress RSS feed](http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/how-to-edit-the-wordpress-rss-feed/)

Reference 2: [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [help > deleted answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Comment: @Richzendy, these references are just resizing the original image but still download the whole original image.